Why is PDF text extraction not working properly?
I am currently encountering the following problem. I am using the PDF Management VBO and use it to extract text from a pdf. For this i am using an action stage and save the text to a data item. When i run the RPA, the tool has a succes in extracting the text (the data item indicates there a 2000 characters), but whenever i open the data item and try to find out what the VBO found, there is no text in it. What could be the reason?
It currently looks like this:  https://i.sstatic.net/Ap3QjP8J.png
The PDF is readable and copyable.
The code in the "PDF Management - Extract All Text" code stage is:
Success = true;
ErrorMessage = "No Error";
OutputText = string.Empty;
try
{
    Extract_Text et = new Extract_Text();
    OutputText = et.Extract_All_Text(PDFFilePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Success = false;
    ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
}

Thanks in advance
